# How to read data from csv and print out specifics in python

Tags: python, csv, input

So I have a csv file with a bunch of bridge data. There's 25 bridges and each bridge number is in column 1. The rest of the columns have corresponding bridge condition data. For example in row 1, 1 is the bridge number, 6 is the
condition rating in 1992, 8 is the condition rating in 1993, 8 is the condition rating in 1994, 7 is the condition rating in 1995, and so on.

I've written a code so far that asks for the users input which is a bridge number between 1-25 and the output I'm trying to achieve is the various conditions that the inputted bridge number is in and for how many years it's in. For example, bridge 1 has 1 year in condition rating 6, 2 years in condition rating 8, 10 years in condition rating 7 and so on. see the image link.

[image: NBIBridge Pic]

Here's what I've come up with thus far but I'm really new to python and could use some (a lot) of help. Could someone please help me call for the right bridge number from the csv?

```
f = open("NBIBridge.csv", "r")
n = int(input("Please enter a bridge number: "))
while n < 1 or n >25:
    n = int(input("please enter a bridge number >1 and <25: "))

bridge = []
for line in f:
    temp = line.split(",")
    i = int(temp[n])
    j = int(temp[n]) 
    temp = [j,n]
    bridge.append(temp)
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First I would transpose the data such that the bridge numbers are in the first row, these would act as headers for the condition ratings.

Next, I think it's better to represent the data in a dataframe using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
bridge_data = pd.read_csv('NBIBridge.csv')
```

Then loop through each column and group and count the condition ratings. You can choose how you want to display this but I'll just put this in a dictionary for now:

```
bridge_dict = {}
for col in data:
    bridge_dict[col] = data.groupby(col).size()
```